# Filtrar um arquivo

Tags: delphi

Veja se alguém pode me salvar, tenho um programa em que é gerado todo dia um TXT da seguinte forma:

> (16BA=1cc)(83=cliente1@plantao)(80=0)(82=1)(1691=610)(1690(89=cliente@frigorifico)(8A

Preciso criar outro programa simples, que retire dessa lista somente o texto que estiver da seguinte forma: `nomedocliente@empresa`, no caso desse exemplo acima, eu teria que retirar os seguintes dados e salvar em um txt ou até mesmo colocar em um MEMO:

> cliente1@plantao, cliente@frigorifico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eis um exemplo de como poderia ser feito.

## Usando `TStringList`:

```
var
  _file: TStringList; // StringList para carregar o arquivo
  text, textDest, aux: string;
  posIni, posFim: integer;
begin
  _file := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // carrega o arquivo
    _file.LoadFromFile('NOME_DO_ARQUIVO');
    text := _file.Text;

    // para interagir linha a linha do arquivo
    while Pos('@', text) > 0 do
    begin
      posIni := Pos('=', text);
      posFim := Pos(')', text) - 1;
      aux := Copy(text, posIni+1, posFim-posIni);
      if Pos('@', aux) > 0 then
      begin
        if Trim(textDest) = '' then
          textDest := aux
        else
          textDest := textDest + ',' + aux;
      end;
      Delete(text, 1, posFim + 1);
    end;
    
    if Trim(textDest) <> '' then
    begin
      _file.Clear;
      _file.Text := textDest;
      _file.SaveToFile('NOVO_ARQUIVO_NOVO');
    end
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage('Não existem registros!');
    end;
      
  finally
    _file.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

## Usando `TextFile` para obter melhor desempenho

```
var
  _file: TextFile;
  _fileDest: TStringList;
  text, textDest, aux: string;
  posIni, posFim: integer;
begin
  AssignFile(_file, 'orig.txt');
  Reset(_file);
  try
    while not Eof(_file) do
    begin
      ReadLn(_file, text);
      while Pos('@', text) > 0 do
      begin
        posIni := Pos('=', text);
        posFim := Pos(')', text) - 1;
        aux := Copy(text, posIni+1, posFim-posIni);
        if Pos('@', aux) > 0 then
        begin
          if Trim(textDest) = '' then
            textDest := aux
          else
            textDest := textDest + ',' + aux;
        end;
        Delete(text, 1, posFim + 1);
      end;
    end;

    if Trim(textDest) <> '' then
    begin
      _fileDest := TStringList.Create;
      try
        _fileDest.Text := textDest;
        _fileDest.SaveToFile('dest.txt');
      finally
        _fileDest.Free;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage('Não existem registros!');
    end;
  finally
    CloseFile(_file);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: só tem um problema, quando o arquivo é grande, ele trava, tem algo que pode melhorar ? O arquivo .TXT tem 90KB mais tem 5 mil linhas...

Comment: Pode me ajudar nesse exemplo se não for incomodar muito Tiago  ? se fosse usando ReadLN ? se puder eu agradeço muito..

Comment: Muito obrigado @Tiago Silva.

Comment: veja pra ajudar: http://prntscr.com/4t4xax

Comment: Obrigado @Tiago Silva, estou tentando descobrir porque ele trava, meu arquivo tem apenas 80kb, é como se ficasse dando um LOOP entende ? arquivo pequeno vai de boa....tem alguma ideia amigo ?

Comment: acho que descobri aqui, vou testar se der resultado eu corrigo....realmente ta gerando loop...

Answer (score 1):

Contribuindo com a resposta eu utilizaria expressões regulares para resolver o seu problema, é mais simples e eficiente.

Uma aquivo com 10000 foi aberto e processado em 2 segundos.

Veja o código.

```
var
  Texto: string;
  StringList: TStringList;
begin         
    StringList:= TStringList.Create;
    try
      StringList.LoadFromFile( 'c:\aquivo.txt' );

      Texto:= TRegEx.Replace( StringList.Text, '[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+', '' );

      Memo1.Clear;
      Memo1.Text:= Texto;       
    finally
      FreeAndNil(StringList);
    end;    
  end;
```

O projeto completo está em: https://github.com/johnidm/collections-code-kata/tree/master/regular-exprssion-replace

Artigo falando sobre expressões regulares: http://www.devmedia.com.br/expressoes-regulares-com-delphi-revista-clubedelphi-139/24072

Comment: infelizmente não deu certo o jeito que você colocou, ele não filtra os e-mails.

Comment: user7605 os e-mails estão nesse formato "use@user.com.br", ou seja com o ".com" ou ".br", pois a expressão regular que eu criei somente filtra esse formato "user@user".

Comment: Isso mesmo Johni Douglas Marangon,é uma lista que tem vários codigos dentro e não só e-mail entende ? A Outra resposta ali cima funciona, mais com uma lista de 5 mil linhas ela trava.....os e-mails é formato user@user.com.br.

Comment: @user7605 nesse caso é só adptar a expressão regular para reconhecer e-mails, o ".com.br" sempre vai ter ou sera opcional?

Comment: Eu posso adaptar e expressão regular para você

Comment: Me passa um exemplo de arquivo com todas as situações